# How to move partial rows of selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched for hours and cannot find the answer on this.  If I have a table set up in an Excel spreadsheet where

- Cells A1 thru C1 and E1 thru G1 are column headings
- Cells A2 thru G2 and A3 thru G3 are blank
- Column D is empty but filled in black
- Row 4 is also empty but filled in black
- Cell A5=1
- Cell B5=2
- Cell C5=3
- Cell E5=4
- Cell F5=5
- Cell G5=6
- Cell A6=7
- Cell B6=8
- Cell C6=9
- Cell E6=10
- Cell F6=11
- Cell G6=12

This is what I need.

When I select any cell in column C and also select any cell in column E (so, two active cells), I need for the following to happen simultaneously:

1. The row data from the selected column C cell (from column A to
   column C) needs to be cut and pasted to the next available row in
   the top section of the table (the section above "blacked out" row 4)
   which in this case would be row 2, from column A to C.
2. The row data from the selected column E cell (from column E to
   column G) needs to be cut and pasted to the next available row in
   the top section of the table (the section above "blacked out" row 4)
   which in this case would be row 2 as well, from column E to G.
3. A new row needs to be added above the blacked out row.

For example, if I selected, cell C5 (which is 3) and cell E6 (which is 10) at the same time, I want to click a macro button and it to simultaneously do the following:

1. Cut Cells A5 thru C5 (1,2 & 3) and paste it to row 2 under columns A thru C (so A2 would = 1; B2 would = 2; and C2 would = 3)
2. Cut Cells E6-G6 (10, 11 & 12) and paste it to row 2 under columns E thru G (so E2 would = 10; F2 would = 11; and G2 would = 12)
3. A new row needs to be added above the blacked out row, which in this case would mean as soon as all the new data is added up top on row 2, a new blank row would be inserted into row 4 and row 5 is now the blacked out row.

Help!

Comment: You should provide some details of what you tried so other can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not ever ask a question like this again.  This site is about programmers helping other programmers to develop their skills it is not here to provide free code to those who cannot or will not write it for themselves.

Normally I would have responded with some general advice but I have not attempted anything like your requirement and I was not sure if it was possible.  So I wrote your macro as a training exercise for myself.

You must learn VBA if you are to post questions here.  You are required to show that you have tried to design and write your own macro.  Search the web for "Excel VBA Tutorial" or visit a good library and check out their VBA Excel Primers.  There are many good online tutorials and many good books so pick something that is right for you.  Learning the basics will not take long and the time invested will quickly repay itself.

Once you know the basics and you are ready for your next macro, you will have to design that macro. By that I mean break the total requirement into little steps. The first version of your macro should probably only attempt step 1.  This will prove you can achieve step 1 before attempting step 2.  If you have a problem with step 1, post your code here and explain what is going wrong.  That is what this site is best at - helping programmers fix their faulty code. Once step 1 is working, update the macro to complete steps 1 and 2.  Look at my macro.  See how it written in tiny steps with a heading that says what each step is going to attempt followed by the necessary code.  I did not write this macro in a single go; I created it in steps just I am I recommending for you.

I first created a worksheet that matched your specification although I had more rows than you.  I will explain why A9 and A11 are blank later.

[image: Inital state of worksheet]

I coded some of the macro and set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> as a shortcut key to call it.

I selected cells A7 and F11.  I wrote enough of the macro to check that I could identify which cells from the left and and which cells from the right I wanted to move and to which row.  My macro contains `Debug.Print` statements to output the important values to the Immediate Window so I could check my code.  I then added the code to move the correct values to the top.  Once that was working I deleted the copied value from their original location.  I continued writing and testing each little step until the macro was complete.

The first run of the macro changed the worksheet to:

[image: Worksheet after first run of macro]

I next selected A10 and E6. In your specification you say the two halves should be written to row 2.  But row 2 is already occupied.  I need to write to the first row with nothing in column A.  That is row 3. One of the early steps in my macro decides which row it is going to write to.  Clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> produced:

[image: Worksheet after second run of macro]

Next I selected A14 and G14.  The first empty cell in column A is A3 but I do not want to write to row 3 because the row is already used even if column A is empty. The code to identify the row to write to allows for this. Cell A9 was empty so I could test my code handled this situation correctly. Program design is about identifying all these alternative possibilities and designing code that will handle each possibility correctly. Don't expect to think of every alternative on your first go.  As your develop and test your macro, look for situation you had not planned for and adjust your design accordingly.  The next version of the worksheet looked like:

[image: Worksheet after third run of macro]

This is enough to explain how the macro operates when given good instructions.  Notice that the macro tests for bad instructions such as only one cell being selected or both cells being on the same side. As I type this I realise that the code does not check for a selected cell being above the black row. Always be ready to realise your design is not complete and be ready to adjust it. I will leave you with the task of checking that both selected cells are below the black row,

Welcome to StackOverflow and the joys of programming.  Good luck.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

  Const ColLeftLeft As Long = 1        '\  Defines range of lefthand set
  Const ColLeftRight As Long = 3       '/
  Const ColRightLeft As Long = 5       '\  Defines range of righthand set
  Const ColRightRight As Long = 7      '/

  Dim CellSlctd() As String
  Dim Col1Slctd As Long
  Dim Col2Slctd As Long
  Dim ColTemp As Long
  Dim RowFirstBlank As Long
  Dim Row1Slctd As Long
  Dim Row2Slctd As Long
  Dim RowLeft As Long
  Dim RowRight As Long

  Debug.Print Selection.Address

  ' Selection.Address should be something like "$C$5,$E$6"
  ' Split into component cells and extract row and column numbers
  CellSlctd = Split(Selection.Address, ",")
  If UBound(CellSlctd) <> 1 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select exactly two cells", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Row1Slctd = Range(CellSlctd(0)).Row
  Row2Slctd = Range(CellSlctd(1)).Row
  Col1Slctd = Range(CellSlctd(0)).Column
  Col2Slctd = Range(CellSlctd(1)).Column

  Debug.Print "Cell1 (" & Row1Slctd & ", " & Col1Slctd & ")"
  Debug.Print "Cell2 (" & Row2Slctd & ", " & Col2Slctd & ")"

  ' Check one selected cell is in the lefthand column set and
  ' the other is in the righthand column set.
  If (Col1Slctd >= ColLeftLeft And Col1Slctd <= ColLeftRight And _
      Col2Slctd >= ColRightLeft And Col2Slctd <= ColRightRight) Or _
     (Col1Slctd >= ColRightLeft And Col1Slctd <= ColRightRight And _
      Col2Slctd >= ColLeftLeft And Col2Slctd <= ColLeftRight) Then
    ' Good values
  Else
    Call MsgBox("One selected cell must be within the lefthand set " & _
                "and the other must be in the righthand set", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Identify which selection is the lefthand selection
  ' and which is the righthand
  If Col1Slctd >= ColLeftLeft And Col1Slctd <= ColLeftRight Then
    RowLeft = Row1Slctd
    RowRight = Row2Slctd
  Else
    RowRight = Row1Slctd
    RowLeft = Row2Slctd
  End If

  Debug.Print "Left/Right " & RowLeft & "/" & RowRight

  ' Find first blank row from top allowing for column A of a row being empty
  ' Find first blank cell in column A
  If Cells(2, "A").Value = "" Then
    ' A2 blank so probably just started
    RowFirstBlank = 2
  Else
    ' A1 and A2 not empty so jump from A1
    RowFirstBlank = Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).Row + 1
  End If
  ' Loop until find blank row
  Do While True
    ColTemp = Cells(RowFirstBlank, ColRightRight + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If ColTemp = 1 And Cells(RowFirstBlank, ColTemp).Value = "" Then
      ' Have blank row
      Exit Do
    End If
    RowFirstBlank = RowFirstBlank + 1
  Loop

 Debug.Print "FirstBlank " & RowFirstBlank

  ' Copy left and right selected sets to RowFirstBlank
  Range(Cells(RowLeft, ColLeftLeft), Cells(RowLeft, ColLeftRight)).Copy _
                                 Destination:=Cells(RowFirstBlank, ColLeftLeft)
  Range(Cells(RowRight, ColRightLeft), Cells(RowRight, ColRightRight)).Copy _
                                 Destination:=Cells(RowFirstBlank, ColRightLeft)

  ' Delete left and right selected sets
  Range(Cells(RowLeft, ColLeftLeft), _
        Cells(RowLeft, ColLeftRight)).Delete shift:=xlUp
  Range(Cells(RowRight, ColRightLeft), _
        Cells(RowRight, ColRightRight)).Delete shift:=xlUp

  ' Insert row under RowFirstBlank
  Rows(RowFirstBlank + 1).EntireRow.Insert

  ' Delete a cell from blank column to compensate for one inserted
  Cells(1, ColLeftRight + 1).Delete shift:=xlUp

  ' Place cursor in black line to ensure no accidental double run of macro
  Cells(RowFirstBlank + 3, "A").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I apologize for not showing any of the many, many different codes I tried.  I am new at coding and could only get one side to move up, not both...it keeps reading both active cells as one cell, and no matter what I tried, I couldn't make it work...I couldn't figure out how it could select and move non-contiguous ranges based on two simultaneous active cells. Thank you for your step by step advice...I'll keep trying :-)

Comment: I do not understand _"Thank you for your step by step advice. I'll keep trying"._ Apart from the check mentioned at the end of the last but one paragraph, I believe my macro does everything you want. If it does do what you want, I would be grateful if you clicked the outline arrow next to my answer so it turns green.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you were able to come up with the code to do what I'd like to do...wish I could figure out the coding as well.  I appreciate you stating what steps you went thru, but I'm having trouble even properly coding step one in selecting the cells to the right and left of the multiple active cells. I think I'm giving up at this point and will seek the help of a VBA professional, thx!

Comment: Sorry. I have just noticed I omitted the code from the answer.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you!!!!!  I'm on the verge of tears...I don't think I've ever been so happy to see code!  I can't tell you how many hours I've looked into this with no success...thank you, thank you!  You are the BEST!

Comment: Happy you like the code. Sorry I made you wait. I still cannot believe I forgot to include the code and then did not notice it was missing.

Comment: Oh goodness, please don't be sorry...I'm just so very grateful that you not only took the time to send the code but to explain it so well! It works perfectly, and will serve as a very good learning tool for me. I hope you have a great Memorial holiday, and thank you so much again!